# Augeas augtool for Java property files

Tags: augeas

I try to adjust a Java properties file with augeas and can't really get it to work even though my usecase seems very straight forward.

I do have a Neo4j server (on Ubuntu 14.04 - installed from the official packages) with the default neo4j-server.properties file and I want to adjust one property. But even before that I can't even manage to let augtool read anything from that file.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
 sudo augtool --noautoload
 augtool> set /augeas/load/Properties/lens Properties.lns
 augtool> set /augeas/load/Properties/incl "/etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties"
 augtool> load
```

Checking if that worked, with:

```
 augtool> print /files/etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties
```

Doesn't return anything.

My next step would be:

```
 augtool> set /files/etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties/org.neo4j.server.webserver.port 8074
 augtool> save
```

But of course this doesn't make sense atm.

As said before - I use the official package. The properties file can be found in the [Github-Repo of Neo4j](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.3/packaging/standalone/standalone-community/src/main/distribution/text/community/conf/neo4j-server.properties)

I would be really great if someone could help me to automate that adjustment.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't bother with setting up the lens manually when you're using Augeas 1.2, just do:

```
$ augtool -At "Properties.lns incl /etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties"
```

and you're set.

Now, if the file doesn't appear in `/files`, you need to check for parsing errors. Type the following in the augtool session:

```
augtool> print /augeas/files/etc/neo4j/neo4j-server.properties//error
```

and see if it returns anything about failing to parse.

Note: On Augeas 1.4, you could just type `errors` in the session.